# How to convert png file to webp file

Tags: php, wordpress, image

I need to convert an image **(png)** to **(webp)** file.

After uploading a **png** file, the **webp** image has been generated, but the **webp** file didn't copy the transparency of a **png** file, instead it creates a black background.

**This is my php code:**

```
$type = wp_check_filetype($file, null);
$ext = $type['ext'];
if ($ext === 'png') {
    $im = imagecreatefrompng($file);
    imagepalettetotruecolor($im);
    $webp = imagewebp($im, str_replace('png', 'webp', $file));
}
imagedestroy($im);
```

> The version of PHP is 5.6

Comment: Use PHP Webp Library. see here https://github.com/S1SYPHOS/php-webp/blob/master/README.md

Comment: Please Check again  https://github.com/S1SYPHOS/php-webp

Comment: Thanks, but do you have any idea how to fix the issue without using any library?

Comment: No I have no any idea do implement this without any library.

Comment: @JordanLipana I have a solution to this. But it depends on a high enough PHP version. Will post it shortly. I first tested on 5.6 -- no go. Then on 7.2 (correction 7.3.0) -- worked. Will check my changes on 5.6 again, then will post the solution with a disclaimer if the php ver matters. Update: Solution is posted.

Comment: Let it be known that Jordan added the PHP 5.6 bit after I posted my solution. That is, after I told him directly that the transparency for webp doesn't work in PHP 5.6. He then adds 5.6 as a requirement. Seems kinda illogical to me but hey, im just here spinning around a globe.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Tested on 7.3.0 -- works.

DISCLAIMER: May only work on later or some PHP versions.

Only tested on 5.6.15 (didn't work, black background) and 7.3.0 (worked, transparent background).

Here's the code:

```
// get png in question

$pngimg = imagecreatefrompng($file);

// get dimens of image

$w = imagesx($pngimg);
$h = imagesy($pngimg);;

// create a canvas

$im = imagecreatetruecolor ($w, $h);
imageAlphaBlending($im, false);
imageSaveAlpha($im, true);

// By default, the canvas is black, so make it transparent

$trans = imagecolorallocatealpha($im, 0, 0, 0, 127);
imagefilledrectangle($im, 0, 0, $w - 1, $h - 1, $trans);

// copy png to canvas

imagecopy($im, $pngimg, 0, 0, 0, 0, $w, $h);

// lastly, save canvas as a webp

imagewebp($im, str_replace('png', 'webp', $file));

// done

imagedestroy($im);
```

Edit 1. *** PROOF

The PHP GD library relies on the libgd library.

Link:

https://github.com/libgd/libgd

Relevant code on saves (file: gd_webp.c), Excerpt showing respect of Alpha channel when present:

```
            c = im->tpixels[y][x];
            a = gdTrueColorGetAlpha(c);
            if (a == 127) {
                a = 0;
            } else {
                a = 255 - ((a << 1) + (a >> 6));
            }
            *(p++) = gdTrueColorGetRed(c);
            *(p++) = gdTrueColorGetGreen(c);
            *(p++) = gdTrueColorGetBlue(c);
            *(p++) = a;
```

In regards to `static int _gdImageWebpCtx (gdImagePtr im, gdIOCtx * outfile, int quality)`

The PHP code I presented relies on the fact that alpha is indeed respected in the GD library and as such **works** if tested in later PHP version than you are using, specifically I tested in 7.3.0 but may work in early releases after your version.

Comment: Thanks, but my version of PHP is 5.6

Comment: @JordanLipana My solution technically solves your problem. We'll see how this plays out however. Jordan, it simply is not supported by the GD library in 5.6. That version of GD in PHP 5.6 doesn't respect the alpha mode. Google documents 3 modes. The PHP 5.6 doesn't use the alpha channel mode for webp far as my tests went.

Comment: Listen, I had done a job to piece together the final images of coupons based on the GD library late last year so when I saw your question, I jumped on it. I checked the C source for your problem to see if alpha was respected: It is in the latest version. I didnt attempt to track it down to what was used for PHP 5.6. Chances are alpha wasn't supported in PHP then, otherwise why else would there be no solution by anyone thus far for that ver?

Comment: Hi, do you have a link that tells that the GD library in PHP 5.6 is not supported for conversion of png to webp? I need to tell this to my team.

Comment: @JordanLipana Understand what I am claiming before I provide proof. PHP 5.6 supports saves to webp. That is a fact. So I cannot claim as you suggest I am that this is not true. What I am saying however is it does not *respect* the alpha channel which is the result *you* desire of a transparent (not black) backround.

Comment: You can still color the background to whatever you want. White even if thats the color that matches your page or container. However, with transparency as the desired effect for the background, it simply cant happen in PHP 5.6 unless you replace the GD library it uses.

Comment: As for *proof* of what PHP 5.6 can do with the GD library, you could always compile the latest library to your current installation of 5.6. My solution therefore is valid. If you wanted to go down that road.

Comment: The link in question is GitHub of the GD library. I have personally inspected the C code in regards to *webp*. You could second that and do the same to see that indeed the alpha channel is respected on saves. But this would be the latest GD library. Since it doesn't work in PHP 5.6 its safe to infer it wasn't supported at that release.

Comment: @JordanLipana I am curious on how the bounty is awarded however, when the OP refuses the correct answer.

Comment: @JordanLipana I will inquire the moderators about that if this dialog reaches a stalemate.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your effort, but I don't think this is the right answer. Because you didn't give any reference, fallback if it doesn't make the background as transparent or etc.. But I will accept the answer at the grace period of the bounty if there no correct answer from the community in SO.

Comment: I'll give the reference as a link and actual code from the C library of GD, shortly.

Answer (score 0):

You may have to enable the alpha channel and save it.  Maybe try this:

```
$ext = $type['ext'];
if ($ext === 'jpg' || $ext === 'jpeg') {
    $im = imagecreatefromjpeg($file);
    $webp = imagewebp($im, str_replace($ext, 'webp', $file), 70);
} elseif ($ext === 'png') {
    $im = imagecreatefrompng($file);
    imagepalettetotruecolor($im);

    imageAlphaBlending($im, true); // alpha channel
    imageSaveAlpha($im, true); // save alpha setting

    $webp = imagewebp($file, str_replace('png', 'webp', $file));
}
imagedestroy($im);
```

> The version of PHP is 5.6

Comment: Thank you but the code doesn't convert the png to webp. I also modified the `imagewebp($file, str_replace('png', 'webp', $file));` and changed it to `imagewebp($im, str_replace('png', 'webp', $file));` but the result it's still the same, it converts the transparency to black.

Comment: I have a solution to this. But it depends on a high enough PHP version. Will post it shortly. I first tested on 5.6 -- no go. Then on 7.2 -- worked. Will check my changes on 5.6 again, then will post the solution with a disclaimer if the php ver matters.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to copy the source image, if the output format supports full alpha transparency. Instead, it is sufficient to tell GD to preserve the alpha channel when saving:

```
$im = imagecreatefrompng($infilename);
imagesavealpha($im, true);
imagewebp($im, $outfilename);
```

Answer (score -1):

just add :

```
imagealphablending($im, true);
imagesavealpha($im, true);
```

between $im = imagecreatefrompng($file); and imagewebp(..

```
$type = wp_check_filetype($file, null);
$ext = $type['ext'];
if ($ext === 'png') {
  $im = imagecreatefrompng($file);
  imagealphablending($im, true);
  imagesavealpha($im, true);
  $webp = imagewebp($im, str_replace('png', 'webp', $file));
}
imagedestroy($im);
```

put the image somewhere like:

```
<html>
  <body style="background-color:red;">
    <img src="url_of_your_img.webp">
  </body>
</html>
```

and you should see your webp in the proper way

Comment: > Just add `imagealphablending($im, true); imagesavealpha($im, true);`. Myth. Has to be one or the other according to php.net: *Alphablending has to be disabled (imagealphablending($im, false)) to retain the alpha-channel in the first place.* from 
 https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagesavealpha.php